# In ASP.net MVC, I need to pass an array of values in Viewpage which should be hidden and I need to save those hidden field values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.net MVC, I need to pass an array of values in Viewpage which should be hidden and I need to save those hidden field values. I am attaching model, controller and view page.

model

```
 public int[] unit_id { get; set; }
```

Viewpage

```
<td>
  @item.UoM_Name                                                     
  @Html.Hidden("unit_id", new { @Value = item.UoM_Id })                                                       
</td>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Product_Unit(ML_Product_HierarchyModel productmodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var count = productmodel.currency_id_array.Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    ML_Product_Unit_Price unit_price = new ML_Product_Unit_Price();
                    unit_price.Product_Id = productmodel.Product_Id;
                    unit_price.Unit_Price = productmodel.unit_price_array[i];
                    unit_price.UoM_Id = productmodel.unit_id[i];
                    unit_price.Currency_Id = productmodel.currency_id_array[i];
                    db.ML_Product_Unit_Price.Add(unit_price);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }        
            return View();
       }
```

Comment: You cannot bind a hidden input to an array - you need a hidden input for each value in the array. And never attempt to set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. But why would you send the data to the view and then back again unchanged? - if you need it, just get it from the repository again

Answer (score 1):

You can use HiddenFor to keep your array in HTML.

```
    @if (Model.currency_id_array != null)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < Model.currency_id_array.Length; i++)
       {
           @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.currency_id_array[i])
       }
    }
```

And after that you can access your array likes you do in controller.

Answer (score 0):

its better to create a comma separated string from the array and then save it to hidden filed. and at the time of post request convert that string to array again.